# Why do some packages fail to download source in Centos?

Tags: centos, yum, dnf

I'm trying to download package sources in Centos 8 using `dnf download --source`. Why does it work for some packages, but fail for others? Is there a workaround for this?

You can test this in a docker container: `docker run -it centos:8`.

```bsh
$ dnf install dnf-plugins-core

$ dnf download --source acl

acl-2.2.53-1.el8.src.rpm

$ dnf download --source audit-libs

No package audit-3.0-0.13.20190507gitf58ec40.el8.src available.
Exiting due to strict setting.
Error: No package audit-3.0-0.13.20190507gitf58ec40.el8.src available.
```

Same results using `yumdownloader --source`:

```bsh
$ yum install yum-utils

$ yumdownloader --source acl

acl-2.2.53-1.el8.src.rpm

$ yumdownloader --source audit-libs

Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:16 ago on Fri May  8 18:38:13 2020.
No package audit-3.0-0.13.20190507gitf58ec40.el8.src available.
Exiting due to strict setting.
Error: No package audit-3.0-0.13.20190507gitf58ec40.el8.src available.
```

Answer (score 2):

The source RPMs for `audit-3.0-0.13.20190507gitf58ec40` is not in the repo . You can view the current source RPMs at http://vault.centos.org/centos/8/BaseOS/Source/SPackages/ , the latest versions there is `audit-3.0-0.10.20180831git0047a6c` .

There was a problem with the source RPMs not being pushed for CentOS 8.1 as reported at https://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos-devel/2020-April/036764.html . As of last week its still a problem as reported at https://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos-devel/2020-April/036809.html

Your source RPM is at https://koji.mbox.centos.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=6229 but you can't download the src.rpm from that koji for some reason (also reported in the email list).

If you know how source rpms work, you can view all the stuff at https://git.centos.org/rpms/audit/tree/af954e3e9ca986da31a5cbd9bb34af3a5bb3440a . You can clone the repo and use git to get all the files if you need them. I got that by looking at https://git.centos.org/rpms/audit/releases .

Answer (score 0):

I found a few workarounds.

1. You can specify the full version of the package with `dnf download --source`. It still doesn't work for every package, but it does for some.

```bsh
$ dnf download --source acl-2.2.53-1.el8.src
```

2. You can find the source rpms from http://vault.centos.org/8.1.1911/BaseOS/Source/SPackages/
(or similar URLs).

For example, I was able to download `acl-2.2.53-1.el8.src.rpm` from:
http://vault.centos.org/8.1.1911/BaseOS/Source/SPackages/acl-2.2.53-1.el8.src.rpm